# Alternating k-tensors and determinant (theorem 4-6, Spivak)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, exterior-algebra

[image]

I am having troubles understanding this proof. I don't understand how, if $\eta \in \Lambda^n(\mathbb{R^n})$ implies that $\eta = \lambda \cdot \det$ - really I don't see how determinants come from this.

This is theorem 4-6 from spivak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from the fact that $\bigwedge^n (T^*M)$ (in other words, the space of $n$-forms on an $n$-dimensional manifold) is 1-dimensional. Since the determinant is one such form, all others are scalar multiples of it.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense.. thank you!